# Load previous page when clicking back button in browser

Tags: reactjs

**GOAL**: When I click the back button in the browser, I want the ***previous*** page to load.

Currently, when I click the back button in my `ProductDetailsPage.js` file, my app reverts to localhost:3000 **without** a forward slash.

How can I ensure when I click the back button in the browser that my app will load `localhost:3000/` **with** a forward `/`

Here is the code for the page I'm clicking back from:

```js
const addToBasket = () => {
    // dispatch item into data layer
    dispatch({
      type: "ADD_TO_BASKET",
      item: {
        name: product.name,
        brand: product.brand,
        image: product.image,
        price: product.price,
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <img src={product.image} />
      <h3>{product.brand}</h3>
      <h1>{product.name}</h1>
      <p>${product.price}</p>
      <button onClick={addToBasket}>Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My app should revert to the page `Feed.js` with following code:

```js
return (
    <div className="feed">
      <div className="feed__cards">
        {products.map((product) => (
          <ProductCard
            image={product.image}
            brand={product.brand}
            name={product.name}
            price={product.price}
            id={product.id}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look likes it's working now. I reset my server and worked like a charm.